# Moving events between several calendars on Start Screen

Tags: windows, windows-8, calendar

I received a new computer for xmas and it has Windows 8. (I know but I'm getting used to it.) I set up 3 calendars thru the new start screen.  Office, Field, Personal. I need to be able to move an event from Office to Field calendar, is this possible?  Or do I have to delete and start a new 'event'?

Answer (score 0):

Log in at [Outlook.com](http://outlook.com), and switch to calendar using the menu in the upper left corner. In the web interface, you can change the calendar when editing an event.

I also hope that this functionality will come to the desktop app very soon.